# how to pick the birthday labels from the contacts in Addressbook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I working with the Addressbook for fetch the contacts list with their labels. (like mobile, main, home, work, fax..etc). I fetched the phone, email labels from the contacts but i did not fetch the birthday, anniversary labels. Here is my code for birthday class.

```
        ABMultiValueRef dateofbirth1 = ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);    // Assign the Date Of birth
         NSString *dob1=[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:(__bridge NSDate *)(dateofbirth1) dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:0];  // Changing to string format using Date Formatter.
          if(!(dob1==nil))
          {
              // DOB is Not Nill
           }
```

**Here is my fetch the BirthDay Label Code**

```
             if([arrayOfDatesAsStrings count]>0)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < [arrayOfDatesAsStrings count] ; j++)
                            {
   **//This is the fetching birthday label code and following code is crashed** 

                                CFStringRef locLabel1 = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex((__bridge ABMultiValueRef)(dob1), j);

                                NSString *phoneLabel1 =(__bridge NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(locLabel1);

                                 personD.dateOfBirth = phone1;

                                NSLog(@" %@  %@",phoneLabel1,personD.dateOfBirth);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Date Of Birth was Not set ");
                        }
```

What can i do for this? can Any one help me? The Crash Error Message is :
    "Thread 1:Exc_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x38)"

Comment: If it crash, what's the error message?

Comment: Thread 1:Exc_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address=0x38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch contacts from devices

```
if (isIOS9) { //checking iOS version of Device

    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];

    //keys with fetching properties
    NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey,CNContactPostalAddressesKey, CNLabelWork, CNLabelDateAnniversary];

    NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];
    DLOG(@"cnContacts %lu",(unsigned long)cnContacts.count);

    if (error) {
        //error
    } else {

        for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {

            //iterate over cnContacts to get details
        }

    }

} else {

    //for below iOS 9
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    CFArrayRef arrPersons = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex count = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
    NSLog(@"cnContacts %lu",(unsigned long)count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        ABRecordRef record = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(arrPersons,i);

        //use kABPersonBirthdayProperty to get b’day
        NSString *birthDay = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty));
        NSLog(@“B’day %@”, birthDay);
    }

}
```